# Multidimensional array access/(de)referencing

Tags: perl

So, I was experimenting with multidimensional arrays and realized that I could access them in different ways, but accomplish the same task (see code below).  When using strict/warnings, Perl told me that I shouldn't use the forms denoted in the comments by **.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @a=();

push @a, [([1,1,1])];
push @a, [([2,2,2],[2,2,2])];
push @a, [([3,3,3],[3,3,3],[3,3,3])];
push @a, [([4],[4,4,4],[4,4,4],[4,4,4],[4,4,4],[4,4,4])];

print scalar(@a)."\n"; #Prints Size of outer array == 4

print scalar(@{@a[3]})."\n"; #Prints number of arrays in slot 3 of @a == 6 **
#or alternatively
print scalar(@{$a[3]})."\n"; #Prints number of arrays in slot 3 of @a == 6 

print scalar(@{@{@a[3]}[0]})."\n"; #Prints size of array in @a of (3,0) == 1  **
#or alternatively
print scalar(@{$a[3][0]}); #Prints size of array in @a of (3,0) == 1
```

Is there actually a functional difference in the two examples above?  Why are the lines with ** worse than the other lines?  Is it simply that they're more confusing than their counterparts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$a[...]   # array element
```

returns the one element identified by the index expression, and

```
@a[...]   # array slice
```

returns all the elements identified by the a number of elements.

As such,

- You should use `$a[EXPR]` when you mean to access a single element in order to convey this information to the reader. In fact, you can get a warning if you don't.
- You should use `@a[LIST]` when you mean to access many elements or a variable number of elements.

There's another differences between the two, and it's subtle: The index expression for an array element is evaluated in scalar context, while the index expression for an array slice is evaluated in list context.

```
sub f { return @_; }

$a[ f(4,5,6) ]     # Same as $a[3]
@a[ f(4,5,6) ]     # Same as $a[4],$a[5],$a[6]
```

Answer (score 1):

This particular issue is not related to references or dereferencing. You get the nth element of an array @a with the syntax $a[n]. This is inspired by English language ("this" element out of "these" elements).

@a[] is used to get an array slice, e.g., @a[0,1,2];